# Generate a report in the most optimal way

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE users (
userid INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, 
age INT
)
GO
CREATE TABLE userstatus(
userstatusID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, 
statusid INT, 
userid INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.users(userid)
)
GO
```

Some sample data:

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.users
        ( age )
VALUES  ( 15  -- age - int
          ),
        ( 20 ),
        ( 25 );

INSERT  INTO dbo.userstatus
        ( statusid, userid )
VALUES  ( 1, 1 ),
        ( 1, 2 ),
        ( 1, 3 ),
        ( 2, 1 ),
        ( 3, 1 ),
        ( 2, 2 );
```

Now I want to get the sum of user ages, and the sum of user ages that has status=2.

Something like:

```
Age with status = 2:  35
Total Ages:           60
```

Comment: You should present all the details of your question at the outset.  Incrementally adding details to your question frustrates the process of providing answers.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you, but I remember about the details after the provided answer. So I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems quite straightforward:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN us.userid IS NOT NULL THEN u.age END) FilteredAge,
        SUM(u.age) TotalAge
FROM dbo.users u
LEFT JOIN dbo.userstatus us
    ON u.userid = us.userid
    AND us.statusid = 2
;
```

**Updated:**

In the case of the same user having multiple same status in the `dbo.userstatus` table, you can use:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN us.userid IS NOT NULL THEN u.age END) FilteredAge,
        SUM(u.age) TotalAge
FROM dbo.users u
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT userid
            FROM dbo.userstatus 
            WHERE statusid = 2) us
    ON u.userid = us.userid
;
```

Comment: thanks for help. I have updated my question one more time. So know I have 3 tables, and I want to have the sum of ages based on location also.

Comment: No, please do **NOT** update the question one more time. Your questions has already been answered.  You can mark an answer as accpted. If you have additional problems, post another question.

Comment: @ArtashesKhachatryan - Since a moderator closed your other question as a duplicate, stating this answer was close enough to what you wanted that you should be able to get there from here, why don't you (the OP, not this answerer) try making the necessary modifications? If you run into problems, then perhaps posting the situation and the query you're working with that's giving you a problem would be acceptable as a new question. This would also give you the chance to remember all the issues you need to deal with, and incorporate everything at once.